# Include code from file into RMarkdown when filename is variable

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I want to have an R chunk in RMarkdown that includes code from an external file.

I want to include the file, rather than embed its contents directly, because the external file contains code that is shared between various projects and scripts, and I want to be sure that each program uses the most recent version.  The `code = ...` chunk option is made for this.

The following method works fine *if* I knit the whole document.  However, if I try to run the individual chunks inside Rstudio (as required during development) I get an error `"Error in readLines(include_file) : object 'include_file' not found"`.

How do I get this to work so I can run chunks from within Rstudio?

### Reproducible example:

#### First create some include files

```
write_lines("x = 1", 'include_1.r')
write_lines("x = 2", 'include_2.r')
write_lines("x = 3", 'include_3.r')
write_lines("x = 4", 'include_4.r')
```

#### Then put the following into a .Rmd file

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
include_file = list.files(pattern = '^include_.+[Rr]$')
include_file = include_file[which.max(file.info(include_file)$mtime)]
```

I want to embed an R code from a file like this:

```{r, code = readLines(include_file)}
```

Then use the objects from the include file

```{r}
print(x)
```
````

This is what the output looks like when I knit the whole document

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't want to just source the scripts within a chunk?

Comment: Thanks @camille - yes that would avoid the error, but then you don't get to see the sourced code in the output document.

Comment: Ahh I see. And I guess it would be too redundant to source in one chunk and call `readLines` in another...

Comment: Actually that's the current cludge I'm using right now.  Hoping for something neater and more idiomatic.

Comment: See this previous issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501622/making-knitr-run-a-r-script-do-i-use-read-chunk-or-source that points to this https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/externalization/.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a file `source.R` with the following content:

```
# first code chunk to be included
## @knitr cc_1
var1 <- runif(10)
var2 <- runif(10)
tmp <- sum(var1)
## @knitr end_cc_1

# second code chunk to be included
## @knitr cc_2
prod(var1, var2)
## @knitr end_cc_2
```

Then you first have to read the file:

````
```{r}
knitr::read_chunk("source.R")
```
````

then you can call the code chunks from the source file like so:

````
```{r}
<<cc_1>>
print(tmp)
<<cc_2>>
```
````

Note that everything can be in the same code chunk but `read_chunk()`
must be called before `<<cc_1>>` and as in this case `<<cc_2>>` requires `tmp`
`<<cc_1>>` must be called before `<<cc_2>>`.

BTW if you want to evaluate a bunch of code silently you can use `include = FALSE`, 
e.g.

````
```{r include = FALSE}
<<cc_1>>
```
````

then, you can call element of `<<cc_1>>`, e.g.

````
```{r}
print(tmp)
```
````

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of `read_chunk`, (and use it with Lyx).  Unfortunately it's not compatible with caching, afaik.  Hence the desire to use `code =` instead.

Comment: I see, so it's as if you cannot use the first code chunk to run the second unless you knit the entire document, right?

Comment: Also, I tested this and it does not allow you to run the individual chunks interactively in Rstudio.  Only seems to work when you knit the whole document... so doesn't answer the qestion unfortunately.  Thanks anyway.